# Connecting to datamart in C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, powerbi

I tried to Google or search here for any tips but couldn't find one, so I had to create a new post.

I'm trying to figure out how to connect to a Datamart within .Net, or simply how the connection string should be formatted. I've never worked with Datamart before, but I'm assuming it's the service associated with Power BI. The only information I got is a type of URL(?) with the following format

> ****.datamart.pbidedicated.windows.net

Also is there any nuget I should install to access the data more easily? Any tip is greatly appreciated.

Comment: From some documentations it's a concept of data storage, not a product. So if you were to connect to a SQL database, then you'll have to search for that. If you're using a Spreadsheet, then you'll have to lookup that.

Answer (score 1):

Datamarts only support AAD auth. eg

```
string ConnectionString2 = @"Server=****.datamart.pbidedicated.windows.net; Authentication=Active Directory MSI; Encrypt=True; User Id=You@yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com; Database=testdb";
```

Follow the instructions for connecting to [Azure SQL with Azure Active Directory Authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: Thank you for the information, I'll read deeper into it